# Is it possible to creat a derived object from a base object through downcast?

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

Base class

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base()=default;
    virtual void f(){cout << "base class\n";}
    virtual ~Base(){}
};
```

Derived class

```
class Derive : public Base
{
public:
    Derive()=default;
    void f() override {cout << "derived class\n";}
};
```

main function

```
int main()
{
    Base* bsd = new Base;
    Derive* dru = new Derive;

    if(Derive* drd=dynamic_cast<Derive*>(bsd)){
        drd->f();
        cout << "downcast successful\n";
    }else{
        cout << "downcast failed\n";
    }

    if(Base* bsu=dynamic_cast<Base*>(dru)){
        bsu->f();
        cout << "upcast successful\n";
    }else{
        cout << "upcast failed\n";
    }

    delete bsd;
    delete dru;
}
```

It turns out upcast works fine, while downcast failed. It seems makes sense that way. If the derived class contain member objects that are not declared in the base class and do not have default constructors, what gonna happen during downcast?

Besides, the target pointer `*drd(*bsd)` created through `dynamic_cast` points to the same object with the pointer `*bsu(*dru)` to be cast. So delete once will be enough. We will not have a dangling pointer, right?

Comment: static cast the drived class instead of dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casting does not create anything new or changes objects in any way. Casting changes the interpretation of an existing object, so if an object is not a `Derive`, there is no way to make it a `Derive` through casting.

Note that `Derive` is also a `Base`, because inheriting creates an "is a" relationship. That's why upcasting works: all it does is telling the compiler that it should treat the pointed to object as `Base`, even though the object is actually `Derive`.

It makes no difference in your program, so here is an illustration of what the cast does:

```
class Derive : public Base
{
public:
    Derive()=default;
    void f() override {cout << "derived class\n";}
    void added() {cout << "hello" << endl; }
};

dru->added(); // Works
Base* bsu=dynamic_cast<Base*>(dru);
bsu->added(); // Does not compile
```

Essentially, the cast "hides" added interfaces from the compiler, ordering it to treat a `Derive` object as if it were `Base`. Of course, the overrides continue to be called correctly, because the overriden member-functions are part of the `Base`'s interface.

Comment: `@das` In that sense, it's kinda like slicing. However, if two pointers point to the same object, as a pointer does not have a type, why the compiler does not recognise `bsu->added()`?

Comment: `@das` What's more, if I change `dynamic_cast` to `static_cast`, `bsu->added()` in the upcast part still doesn't compile, while `drd->added()` during the downcast process works fine! It's like a new object is created during the process. Why is that?

Comment: @MiloLu The pointer does have a type - that's what decides if the compiler is allowed to do certain operations or not. Upcast/downcast is an expression. It produces another pointer, without changing the original pointer. Casting `drd` does not change what you can do to `drd`, because neither its type nor its value is going to change.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I got your question right, but yes, you can safely delete a derived class using a base pointer, if the destructor is `virtual`.

A "dangling pointer" is something different: After you have deleted `bsd` and `dru`, you can not use these pointers anymore, they have become dangling pointers, because they point to deleted memory that you don't own anymore.

Comment: `@alain` The dangling pointers will be cleaned up automatically when they go out of scope, right?

Comment: Yes, the lifetime of the pointers end when they go out of scope, and the lifetime of the objects they point to end with `delete`.

Answer (score 0):

dynamic_cast checks run-time type check and provides a safe conversion. If a meaningful conversion is possible then you'd get a valid object after downcast. As you pointed out, in your example the underlying object was of "base class". Run time type check failed. However if the underlying object was of "derieved class" dynamic_cast would have succeeded. ex:

```
class CBase
{
public:
    CBase(void);
    virtual ~CBase(void);

    virtual void identify() 
    {
        std::cout << "base class" << std::endl;
    }
};

class CDerieved : public CBase
{
public:
    CDerieved(void);
    virtual ~CDerieved(void);
    virtual void identify()
    {
        std::cout << "Derieved class" << std::endl;
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CDerieved* pderieved = new CDerieved;
    pderieved->identify();

    CBase* pb = static_cast<CBase*>(pderieved);
    pb->identify();

    CDerieved* pd1 = dynamic_cast<CDerieved*>(pb);
    pd1->identify();

    return 0;
}
```

The above code will succeed.

But please remember, if you find needing a downcast, then the design needs to be revised.